# [JAVA]arraylist of arrays iterator

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator, jtextarea

as the title says i'm heaving problem while iterating arraylist of arrays.
Here is my definition: `public static ArrayList<JTextArea[]> ta;`
here is how i read value from it:

```
Iterator<JTextArea[]> i = Interface.ta.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            JTextArea[] t = (JTextArea[]) i.next();
            ret += t[0].getText() + ", ";
        }
```

The JTextArea array is always an array of four elements and in this while I have to read the text of the firstone.
The problem is simple, the "next()" method gives me every JTextArea object, not the complete array made of 4 JTextArea s.

Any way to get the Next() method pick all the array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't have to cast , `i.next()` should return `JTextArea[]`. Your `i.next` should return `JTextArea[]`

Comment: **Please** post your code! At least a minimal self contained example. Can you show us your problem using `Iterator<String[]>` with input and output?

Comment: If `i.next()` doesn't give you an array in `t`, how are you being able to access `t[0]`?

Comment: show Interface.ta insertion.

Comment: ok, I have not explained well my problem, sorry.
the problem is i.hasNext() is being called for every element of the arrays inside the JTextArea[] so, if my arraylist contains only one array made of 4 elements the while is being executed 4 times. There is a way to limit this execution to one time per array?

Answer (score 2):

Use `For Each` instead of `Iterator`

```
for (JTextArea[] jTextAreaArray : ta) {
 // Use jTextAreaArray to do your process.
}
```

It is very simple to use rather than `Iterator`

To get Individual Objects use.

```
 for (JTextArea[] jTextAreaArray : ta) {
   for(JTextArea jTextArea : jTextAreaArray ){
    // Do your Process with Individual jTextArea.
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference t[1], t[2], t[3] for the other 3 in the t array, so your codes should be:

```
  ArrayList<JTextArea[]> ta=null;
  // setup ta here;

  String ret = "";
  Iterator<JTextArea[]> i = ta.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
     JTextArea[] t = i.next();
     ret += t[0].getText() + ", ";
     ret += t[1].getText() + ", ";
     ret += t[2].getText() + ", ";
     ret += t[3].getText() + ", ";
     // or
     for (int x=0; x<t.length; x++) {
        ret += t[x].getText() + ", ";
     }
  }
```